# JavaFX: Interrupt loop then update UI in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I know there are million questions about updating UI in javafx from differents thread, but in my case I am working with one scene only and I would like interrupt a loop while and then I start another thread that will update UI.

**I'm testing the following code :**
Class main :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("My project");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800,600,Color.LIGHTBLUE);
    Label lab = new Label("This is a test");
    root.getChildren().add(lab);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    GuiUpdate gu=new GuiUpdate(stage,root);
    int i=0;

    while(i<5)
    {

        synchronized (this) {

            gu.getThread().start();
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

my class GuiUpdate, I have 2 button.
First button execute an action.
Second Button stop this Thread and set previous Scene property.

```
public GuiUpdate(Stage stage, Parent root){
    this.root=new Group();
    thread = new Thread(this);
    oldRoot=root;
    this.stage=stage;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("position 3 : runner");
            Button[] button=new Button[2];
            button[0]=new Button("Action");
            //Set action for button 0

            button[1]=new Button("Back");
            button[1].setOnAction(e -> {
                notify();
                stage.getScene().setRoot(oldRoot);
                getThread().interrupt();
            });

            root.getChildren().addAll(oldRoot,button[0],button[1]);
            stage.getScene().setRoot(root);
        }
    };

    if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
        System.out.println("Position 1");
        runner.run();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Position 2");
        Platform.runLater(runner);
    }
}

public Thread getThread(){return thread;}
```

}

**Problem :**
When I run project,  Platform.runLater(runner) seems not to be working and Application freeze because "main Thread" is waiting

Comment: I don't understand you creating the `Buttons` inside the thread. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Sedrick I would like to add and remove buttons "dynamically". If I put ` while(x) root.getChildren.add(new Button("example") `, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you runnable is only going to create `Buttons`, I don't see the need the need to do this.

Comment: You only need a `Thread` if you are going to do some long-running `Task`. You don't need a `Thread to add `Nodes` dynamically.